# Which Nativescript module is better for http requests - http or fetch?

Tags: nativescript

Which Nativescript module is better for http requests - http or fetch?

Planning on doing GETs and POST operations - mostly simple with no cookies and state requirements.

But I would like to get fine control over the XMLhttprequest object - e.g. setting the timeout value etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think one is particularly better than the other, though my preference is to use `http` as it's more consistent as far as implementation style as other Angular and node modules. If I'm not mistaken, it actually wraps the core node `http` module and just extends it to make it work for both iOS and Android platforms natively.

That said, `http` looks to be better documented and has the `HttpRequestOptions` interface where you can directly set the `timeout` as you mentioned wanting control over: [http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/*http*.httprequestoptions.html](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_http_.httprequestoptions.html)

Comment: The `timeout` option is an important feature.  Particularly if you want to build an app that works for people that move in and out of net coverage.  If my tests are correct the `fetch` module just hangs if the connection never returns.

Comment: Seeing the same problem here. For some reason, sometimes, my fetch or http request does not arrive on backend immediately, but after a minute or so, even when my connection is solid, which is super weird. At least now I will be able to check for it with timeout option.